# How to point domain to subdomain and index it

Tags: .htaccess, cross-domain, subdomain

I have a domain: www.example.com. I create a subdomain like: subdomain.example.com. When i go to that domain, i get what i want, and land on the subdomain uri.

Now the issue: 
i want to point www.mysite.com to subdomain.example.com and have it indexed by google. I can do this with a redirect, but the new site won't be indexed by google. I know that it is possible with .htaccess, im i right?

If anyone can help me out or point me into the right direction, i would be very pleased :)

Comment: There isn't an htaccess directive that will tell google to index your site. You could put something in there to do a `301 Moved Permanently` redirect to the uri and whenever they decide to index your site again they will get those and ideally update the urls, but more likely just re-index them and you lose any ranking you had.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I take that you have

- A primary site: *subdomain.example.com*
- A secondary site: *www.mysite.com* (the new site that you want to point to your primary site)

#### Do the following steps:

1. Go the Domain Control Panel site of your *Primary Domain Register* and find the **Canonical domain name** for *subdomain.example.com*
2. Go the Domain Control Panel site of your *Secondary Domain Register* and add a `CNAME` record pointing to your primary site's **Canonical domain name**.

You may have to wait for a few minutes for the changes to take effect.

**Note**: Your *primary domain* register may require other changes to your *secondary domain records* for this to work.